# c# postback causing issues with username/staffcode

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I'm having a very hard time editing this page on my webapp. The problem is when the page is loaded it automatically grabs the user name and places it in a column that says...Last edited by: The user doesn't have to touch the page and it'll auto grab the name. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
     CheckMatterOverride(); // fix: 
     MarketValueAnalysisID.Value = CurrentMatter.MarketValueAnalysis.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Year == CurrentMatter.DocketYear); 
     MatterNumber.Value = CurrentMatter.MatterNumber; 
     SaveButton.Click += new EventHandler(Save_Click); 
     if (!Page.IsPostBack) { 
         BindMVAPropertyData(); 
     }
 } 

   private void BindMVAPropertyData()
    {
        PropertyInformation.BindMVAPropertyData();

        if (CurrentMVA != null)
        {
            ucNavigation.CurrentEntity = CurrentMVA;
            ucNavigation.SetNavigationValues();

        }
    }
```

The ucNavigation.SetNavigationValues is where the user name/staff code appears. Commenting it out doesn't help because once the user clicks save their code should appear. Here's a snippet of the UCclass.cs

```
  public SSM.Classes.MarketValueAnalysi CurrentMVA
    {
        get 
        {
            if (CurrentMatter.MarketValueAnalysis.FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                return CurrentMatter.MarketValueAnalysis.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                var newMVA = CurrentMatter.AddNewMarketValueAnalysis();
                CurrentContext.SaveChanges();
                return newMVA;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: how to stop the username/staff code from auto loading when the page is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this function `BindMVAPropertyData` gets called in your `Page_Load` ?

If so, then do this:

```
if(!isPostBack) {
  BindMVAPropertyData()
}
```

Comment: the if is already in the Page_Load. It looks like this :     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckMatterOverride();

            // fix: MarketValueAnalysisID.Value = CurrentMatter.MarketValueAnalysis.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Year == CurrentMatter.DocketYear);
            MatterNumber.Value = CurrentMatter.MatterNumber;
            SaveButton.Click += new EventHandler(Save_Click);
            
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindMVAPropertyData();
            }

Comment: It looks like `BindMVAPropertyData` should not be called on initial page load, given the code snippet you have provided, because of the `if (!IsPostback)` clause.  Any chance it is populated anywhere else? Be sure to check the code in any base page or inherited classes as well.